# How to pull hrefs from htmlbody

Tags: apex, before-trigger, emailmessage

I want to write a trigger that pulls links(href) ONLY from the HtmlBody onto a custom field on Case.

For instance, i have -

```
This is Yahoo
<br><br>
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo link</a>
<br><br>
This is google<br><br>
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google link</a>
```

I want the output as -

```
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo link</a>
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google link</a>
```

My code so far

```
trigger CaptureHref on EmailMessage (before insert) {

SObjectField[] fields = new SObjectField[] {
Case.Hrefs__c
};

List<String> links = new List<String>();

Pattern anchors = Pattern.compile('<a.+?href="([^"]+?)"');  

map<Id,EmailMessage> MapEM = new map<Id,EmailMessage>();

for(EmailMessage newEmail: trigger.new){

if(newEmail.Incoming = false && newEmail.Subject.contains('Response') )


MapEM.put(newEmail.parentId, newEmail);
}
List<Case> clist = new List<Case>([Select Id, Hrefs__c from Case WHERE Id in: MapEM.keyset()]);

For (Case c: clist){

Matcher m = anchors.matcher(MapEM.get(c.Id).HtmlBody);


    while (m.find()) 
    links.add(m.group());
    c.Hrefs__c = String.join(links, '\n');

} 

update clist;


}
```

Please let me know how to get this done.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice question.Someone ask me same question in a interview at starting of my carrier.@Khyber

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression is almost correct. I would use `<a.+<\/a>`. You don't know if `href` will be the first property (or if there will be multiple spaces after `a`), and you don't want to skip links that don't conform to your definition if you can avoid it.

Another thing you need to correct is to actually instantiate a `Pattern` (not a `Matcher`).

```
Pattern anchors = Pattern.compile('<a.+<\\/a>');
```

Now you can create a matcher for a specific `Case`. You should move your code to an `Apex Class` where you can define a helper method. Something like:

```
public with sharing class CaseServices
{
    static Pattern anchors = Pattern.compile('<a.+<\\/a>');
    public static String getHrefs(String input)
    {
        Matcher m = anchors.matcher(input);
        List<String> links = new List<String>();
        while (m.find()) links.add(m.group());
        return String.join(links, '\n');
    }
}
```

You'll need to play around with the delimiter. Depending on how you want to use the output, perhaps `<br />` would be more appropriate than `\n`.

Comment: '<a.+?href="([^"]+?)"` might be even better, especially if they want to use `m.group(1)` to get just the link itself instead of all the fluff around it.

Comment: Indeed. Though if they want just the actual `href` I was initially thinking it should just be `(href=['"])([^'"]+)`. That's how I read it at first glance.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Nothing happens, it doesn't capture the hrefs. Am i missing anything? Updated the code in my question.

Comment: This expression works for me given the sample you originally posted. What's the content in your `HtmlBody` field? Can you edit your post to include that?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Hi Adrian, the content is same, i have not changed my content, what i meant earlier was - i edited my question with the code i am trying to run. When i send an email with this content, my custom field on the parent case is not getting updated with hrefs...

Comment: @AdrianLarson - right now wit your code, the output is from the first hyperlink to the last hyperlink in the content but not just the links - i,e. <a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank">Yahoo link</a>
<br><br>
This is google<br><br>
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google link</a> can you let me know how to truncate the fluff between the links? Appreciate your time!

Comment: @AdrianLarson - i am trying to use run this via execute anonymous to update old cases in bulk, but all the cases are being updated with the response of the first case in the loop, is this being caused by while statement? can you think of anything that can make this work for updating cases in bulk? appreciate your help!

Comment: Ask a new question for that and reference this one. Make sure to include your code. @Khyber

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use the [XmlStreamReader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_XmlStream_reader.htm) class instead. Basically, you just loop through the stream, watching for href attribute. Something like this:

```
XmlStreamReader reader = new XmlStreamReader(xmlString);
while(reader.hasNext()) {
    reader.next();
    if(reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT && 
       reader.getLocalName() == 'a') {
        for(Integer i = 0, m = reader.getAttributeCount(); i < m; i++ ) {
            if(reader.getAttributeLocalName(i) == 'href') {
                System.debug(reader.getAttributeValueAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also realized that there might not be an outer "shell" (required by XML), so you might need to this to create the reader:

```
XmlStreamReader reader = new XmlStreamReader('<root>'+xmlString+'</root>');
```

Comment: I think it should be `i = 0;`, not `i = 0,`? Looks like kind of a pain to work with haha.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Updated the code with a working example I wrote up in dev console.

Comment: @AdrianLarson No, it's not very forgiving. I actually had to rely on writing code instead of the docs, which suggested it worked differently.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Thanks a lot for your response, appreciate it, i am about to try your code, i might end up with so many questions...

Comment: @sfdcfox - i know that this is already a piece of cake for me,  at the end do i need to capture the final output into my custom case field something like case.hrefs__c = reader.get text(); is this correct? Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Khyber yes, you can replace the debug statement with whatever you need to do

Comment: @sfdcfox - Hi, my custom field is not capturing hrefs from the outgoing email, i replaced the debug statement with case.hrefs__c = reader.getAttributeValueAt(i); anything you can suggest here, appreciate your time!

Comment: Seeing your updated attempt would probably be useful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41627/discussion-between-khyber-and-sfdcfox).