# Need help to update cases in bulk

Tags: apex, bulk, execute-anonymous

I am trying to update cases in bulk referring to a question [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128554/how-to-pull-hrefs-from-htmlbody)

i am trying to run a script via execute anonymous to update old cases in bulk, but all the cases are being updated with the response of the first case in the loop, works fine if i run this for 1 case a time.

I might be missing something that is simple.

How to make this work to update cases in bulk?

```
List<Case> caseList = [Select LastModifiedDate, Response__c, Hrefs__c FROM Case WHERE LastModifiedDate != TODAY limit 100];

List<String> links = new List<String>();

for(Case cs :caseList)
{

Pattern anchors = Pattern.compile('<a.+?</a>');

Matcher mat = anchors.matcher(cs.Response__c);

while (mat.find()) 
links.add(mat.group(0));
cs.Hrefs__c = String.join(links, '\n');

}

update caseList;
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You are not setting links to a new list inside the loop. So everytime you go through the loop, links has already got the values from the previous case(s).

Comment: @DougB - Thanks a lot Doug B, I think Tushar beat you on the answer by secs, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Case> caseList = [Select LastModifiedDate, Response__c, Hrefs__c FROM Case WHERE LastModifiedDate != TODAY limit 100];


for(Case cs :caseList)
{
List<String> links = new List<String>();

Pattern anchors = Pattern.compile('<a.+?</a>');

Matcher mat = anchors.matcher(cs.Response__c);

while (mat.find()) 
links.add(mat.group(0));
cs.Hrefs__c = String.join(links, '\n');

}

update caseList;
```

try to declare the `links` list inside for loop.